# Complex regex match everything between set of characters?

Tags: regex

Regex! This isn't for a specific language. It's for a multi-file renamer that lets you use regex. So I'm just looking for a "pure" regex solution. I'm having trouble finding an answer that fits so I figured I'd ask.

Here is an example of the kinds of strings I'm working with:

```
[998FA551B]-[FIRE]-[#b.c.friends@fams]-[ My.Life.Story.V99A4.NONE.x4X5p-RIEP ]- my.life.story.v99a4.xrsr-riep
```

what I need is to remove everything that **is not** between '-[ ' and ' ]-' or 'dash, open bracket, space' and 'space, close bracket, dash'" and be left with:

```
My.Life.Story.V99A4.NONE.x4X5p-RIEP
```

Thank you!

Comment: Like this? http://regex101.com/r/fT7fI3

Comment: Is there only at most one of these per line?

Comment: That works! And yes, only one per line. That is way less complex than I was making it. Dang. I tested several and it worked perfectly. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match everything *except* the target:

```
^.*-\[ | \]-.*$
```

Then replace matches with a blank to delete.

[See live demo](http://rubular.com/r/VV3YGydlSH) of this regex working with your sample input.

Comment: Thank you but that didn't seem to work. It didn't match anything from my list of actual folders, or with the regex tester in the answer above. This is actually what I need, though :)

Comment: Try it now (I forgot to escape the square brackets!)

Comment: Thanks again! It's better but still not 100%. It leaves the closing bracket and lower-case version... everything to the right of what I want.

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is. I have added a link to this regex working correctly with your example. Please click the link and tell me where the problem is.

Comment: I apologize. It works great. The app I'm using to rename folders has a few options. I had to check "global" (match as many times as possible) and it works perfectly. Thank you again very much! This is going to save me SO much time :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex to capture the name:

```
-\[\s(.+)\s\]-
```

Matched example: `My.Life.Story.V99A4.NONE.x4X5p-RIEP`

**Breakdown:**

```
-           # match the literal dash
\[          # match the opening square bracket (\ escape required)
\s          # match a single whitespace
(           # open capture group
    .+      # match anything at least once ()
)           # close capture group
\s          # match a single whitespace
\]          # match the closing square bracket (\ escape required)
-           # match the literal hash
```

**Demo:** http://regex101.com/r/fT7fI3

Comment: This does, perfectly. Thank you for the breakdown, too. It helps me understand regex a little better. Unfortunately, the first app I was using worked the opposite of the one I had to change to. lol. Sorry. I need to match everything **but** this.